# Is it possible to cast android application on chromecast (not mirror)

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I want to make an android application with a ViewPager for example with a article (name, price...) on each tab. I want to cast this application on a desktop screen with Chromecast and adapt my application (framgents) to the screen size. Is it possible to cast my application using cast button to a chromecast and how do you make this ? Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what you want, but if you open up chrome on your desktop PC and enter chrome://inspect  in the URL field, it will scan your computer for USB devices, or if you are running your app in an AVD, it will find that as well.  If you click Inspect on the listing for your AVD it will capture the current screen of your app and let you inspect the elements that make up the screen.  I'm using it for looking at the html content of a webview.

Answer (score 0):

the SDK doesn't have direct support for this. So, i would say NO.

Though it is doable if the sender side can encode what's on the page, and pass it to the receiver side via custom message channel, but that's totally up to the app to define how to serialize and deserialize the page.